# Psychology books FOR Statistics students

Tags: references, psychology, application

I can find a lot of book recommendations on Statistics for Psychology students. But can anyone suggest some good books **for** a Statistics student who wants to learn about applications of Statistics in Psychology?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this introductory book: Field, A. P. (2017). Discovering statistics with SPSS (5th ed.). London: Sage. https://www.discoveringstatistics.com/books/dsus/

The author is Professor of Child Psychopathology (https://profiles.sussex.ac.uk/p9846-andy-field) and Professor of Quantitative Methods.

The book won several awards, see https://www.discoveringstatistics.com/about/

Comment: Opinion about the book amongst a number of statisticians here is rather less rosy. It has numerous mistakes (examples arise in several questions here on site), it has a number of poor or misleading explanations, and various other issues. Indeed the apparent uncritical regard in which it's held amongst many people in psychology leaves me concerned for the state of statistics in that area of research; the fact that it's won awards only compounds that concern, because it suggests that the committees making the awards are also quite unaware of its many problems.

Comment: If the OP wants to have access to a book that represents the most common practices of applied statistics in psychology, I think that the book is still relevant. Another book that was commonly used in Psychology is "Statistical Methods for Psychology" by author David C. Howell who was Full Professor and Chair of the Department of Psychology at the University of Vermont (he passed away in 2019).

Comment: I agree - it represents a lot of common practice (and indeed, it is an improvement over some other books and the ensuing practice that results from following them), If the OP uses it from the "what is currently common practice" point of view, I'd have no objection.